# C++ Solution for a Analytical Issue

Tags: c++, machine-learning

I am currently working on a project which seeks to analyze the vibrations of a laundry machine throughout its washing cycle.

The program runs on a Raspberry Pi 3, and gets the vibration information from a vibration sensor, which sends out the state using a digital signal (as opposed to an analog signal)

Our current idea is the implement a program which "machine learns" the cycles by recording the first 10 times the laundry machine runs, and stores that information in a text file.

The program does this by running the following loop every 10 milliseconds.

```
for(;;) {
    read state of /sys/class/gpio/export/
    write the state into a vector<bool>
    analyze the bool vector to figure out when the machine is turned on or off (compare against a template vector read from an external txt file)
    if the machine just got turned on, cout a message
    if the machine just gor turned off, cout a message
    }
```

A few problems with our current analysis model:

Because we are recording data every 10 milliseconds, there are always going to be small lags which would make analyzing the live boolian against the template very difficult:
for example:

live boolian vector

```
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
```

template:

```
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
```

even a minute shift in the live data would render the analysis useless. Therefore, what kind of method could I use to be able to shift the data so that the live data:

```
        0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
```

can be compared against the shifted template

```
    0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
```

My guess would be we would need to program an algorithm which constantly checks multiple shifts in both directions to find the shift which is statistically most likely to be the true position of the vector.

Thank you

Comment: It might help if we knew exactly what a 0 and a 1 signified. For example, a 1 might mean movement in any direction, and a 0 might mean no movement. Or a 1 might mean movement in a specific direction, and a 0 might mean movement in the opposite direction. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Whether the machine's on or not seems a pretty coarse thing to detect.  While Entropy's right that we need better information about what the numbers mean, it's likely that you can simply check for e.g. 60 seconds in which there's < X% of 1s as an indication of the machine being off, or > Y% as an indication of being switched on.  It's also possible that it's the number of transitions from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 that are significant, rather than the number of either value.  You could calculate usable X and Y thresholds using your recorded data.

Comment: 1 signifies when the file state is "true" or when the vibration sensor is in motion. However, the state will never be always true even if the laundry machine is shaking the sensor because when the vibration sensor is moving with the force of inertia, it will not register a true. Thus, when the machine  is running, the trues and falses, 1's and 0's will increase at roughly the same rate in the bool vector, and when turned off, the falses will increase while the true stays the same.

Comment: Also, we can't hardcode a time such as "60 seconds" because of the way the laundry machines will behave during a cycle. Unlike a dryer which has a more or less constant pattern of constantly spinning in the same way, a washing machine will at times completely stop vibrating, in order to change the direction of the spin, or to fill the tank up with water. At the same time, some laundry machines on our campus will have different times of completion using the same settings (e.g. Perm Press). Furthermore, each laundry machine will have different wash times for different settings.

Comment: Sounds like you're comparing against a pattern, and the result is something like "it's on" or "it's off", correct? If so, chances are pretty good that an artificial neural network will work pretty well for the job (assuming you can collect a fair amount of known data with it on vs. off).

Comment: Instead of comparing the actual sequence of 1s and 0s you get from the sensor, you might find it more useful to collect statistics about overlapping groups of many bits. For instance, you could collect information about the numbers of consecutive 1s, and consecutive 0s, and the overall frequency of the changes. You could collect averages for these values, such as mean, median, and mode. You could collect the upper and lower quartiles and the interquartile range. You could then compare these statistics to look for a good match.